# Command Button for Approvals on Different Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, commandbutton

I am trying to create an approval process right now, and in order to do so, I have a summary sheet, which current shows the details of the offers and then a detail sheet, where I am keeping a log of what is approved. Currently you type the information of the offer into the second sheet (offer details), and then the approver can view a drop down box to see what is open and needs to be approved. I have everything working, except, I need the approver to click a button and it will send the username of the approver and the date to the corresponding cell on the Offer Detail tab. I have created a key, in H1 which will allow the code to find the correct line what is column B on the offer details page  matches what is in the Summary Tab in H1.

I have this code that I wrote below, but it is not working. The cells where the username needs to go into column M on the offer detail sheet (once it finds the right row based on the key in the summary).  It has to be hardcoded, so I can keep it for audit purposes.

If this doesn't make sense let me know and I will try to clarify.

Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Object
With Sheets("Offer Details")
    Set rng = Sheets("Offer Details").Range("B1:B1000")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = Sheets("Offer Details").Cells(1, 8) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell` will be in column `B`. If you offset that by 12 columns, wouldn't that be column `N`?  Also, since you're using `With Sheets("Offer Details")`, in that `With` statement, you don't need to repeat it. You can simply use a leading `.`, i.e. `Set rng = .Range("B1:B1000")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you need colum **"M"** to be every time, base on your code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Object
Dim inc as Integer
With Sheets("Offer Details")
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B1000")
    For Each cell In rng
        inc = inc + 1
        If cell.Value = .Cells(1, 8) Then
           .Range("M" & inc) = Environ("USERNAME")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason it is still not working. When I press the button nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I just specified the sheet and it worked. Thank you so so much!

Comment: You're welcome. If the problem is solved and if the response was good, can you mark the answer?